# Retrofit 2: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

I am use Retrofit 2. I use test JSON on http://ip.jsontest.com/.It is very simple JSON. Why I am take this error?

In real project i have this ERROR too, but i think, it is because I have very big JSON. And I thy use test JSON. Need HELP))

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $`

**This is JSON**

{
"ip": "54.196.188.78"
}

**My Interface**

```
public interface UmoriliApi {
    @GET(".")
    Call<List<Test>> getData();
}
```

**My Test class**

```
public class Test {
    @SerializedName("ip")
    @Expose
    private String ip;

    public String getIp() {
        return ip;
    }
    public void setIp(String ip) {
        this.ip = ip;
    }
}
```

**My API class**

```
public class App extends Application {

    private static UmoriliApi umoriliApi;
    private Retrofit retrofit;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://ip.jsontest.com/") 
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) 
                .build();
        umoriliApi = retrofit.create(UmoriliApi.class); 
    }

    public static UmoriliApi getApi() {
        return umoriliApi;
    }
}
```

**My MainActivity class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "TAG";
    List<Test> posts;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        posts = new ArrayList<>();

        App.getApi().getData().enqueue(new Callback<List<Test>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Test>> call, Response<List<Test>> response) {
                posts.addAll(response.body());
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: "+posts.size());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Test>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: ");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @GET(".")
   Call<Test> getData(); modified this code

Comment: @Akash Thank. But how i can get list of test? posts.addAll(response.body());

Comment: @Sergey after change your retrofit interface to [@GET(".") Call<Test> getData();] in your case you can do posts.add(response.body());

Answer (score 5):

Basically you are expecting and Array but you received a JSON Object.

As Akash said in the comment:

`Call<List<Test>> getData();`

`List<Test>` is what you write when you expect and Array. You need to write `Call<Test>` for an object Test

You will also have to change the callback.

Comment: Thank. I changed @GET(".") Call<Test> getData(); How I can get List of Test?

Comment: @SergeyRokitskiy: Your JSON does not *have* a list. It has one JSON object. If you want a list, your Web service needs to return a list formatted in JSON.